# Разделить строку регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Функция parse принимает строку и массив с символами (y)~["!", "%",...], которыми он отрежет всю правую часть строки:
строка "Раз, два!, три"    =>    "Раз, два". Или:
"Раз, д%ва!, три"   =>    "Раз, д"

```
function parse(str, y) {
      q = "";
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        q += y[i];
      }
      result = str.split("/[" + q + "]+/");
      return result[0];
    }
```

Логика следующая, режем строку этими символами и возвращаем [0] элемент строки. Если задать жестко str.split(/[!%]+/), то работает корректно. Если вместo !% поставить переменную, не выходит. Скорее всего, что регулярное выражение становится строкой.

Comment: @splash58: php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let aDel = ["!", "%"];

function parse(str, y) {
  let rExp = new RegExp(`[${y.join('')}]`);
  return str.split(rExp)[0];
}

console.log(parse('Раз, два!, три', aDel));
console.log(parse('Раз, д%ва!, три', aDel));
```

Comment: Или `RegExp( y.join("|") )`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: в `[...]` он будет лишним, а без `[...]` велика вероятность, что однажды в массиве разделителей передадут например `.`

Comment: @UModeL, но с квадратными скобками тоже некоторые символы надо экранировать - например, `]` и ```\```.

Comment: @Qwertiy: но, эти символы менее вероятны в качестве разделителя, чем точка. Всё-таки скобки многое сами экранируют. А так, конечно, не без недостатков.

Answer (score 2):

Для вашей задачи можно использовать `ИЛИ` - `|` знак `+` в этом случае лишний

`"Раз, два!, три".split(/%|!/)` // [ "Раз, два", ", три" ]

`"Раз, два%, три".split(/%|!/)` // [ "Раз, два", ", три" ]

`Раз, два!,три%,четыкре".split(/%|!/)` //  [ "Раз, два", ",три", ",четыкре"]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку. Оказалось что массив можно передавать как есть, тоже работает.

```
    function parse(str, arr) {
      regExp = new RegExp(`[${arr}]`);
      return str.split(regExp)[0];
    }

console.log(parse("s#d!f%sl!dfjskdl df%ks sdf ! dsdf! dsf sd f", ["%", "!", "#"]));
```

Comment: Неправильно. Тут ещё по запятой сплитится. Ну и экранирования не хватает.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо.